# Meaning of "bake your noodle"

Tags: meaning-in-context, cleft-constructions

In the movie *The Matrix* 1999, the Oracle said to Neo:

> What's really going to **bake your noodle** later on is, would you still have broken it if I hadn't said anything.

I don't quite understand the meaning of the entire sentence. Just consider *what's really going to bake your noodle*, which doesn't seem to mean anything.

Comment: By the way, the what part is actually a relative clause.  This is called a pseudo-cleft sentence.  http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsAPseudoCleftSentence.htm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Essentially this means that it's going to really make you think about the subject, or more likely confuse the person, as they won't be able to get a grasp on it.

Noodle can be used as a slang term for brain,
**e.g. "Use your noodle!"**

It's basically the same as saying, "This is going to fry your brain.", So in summary, he'll have to think very hard about what he is being told so that he can understand it.

Comment: Thx, I see. Noodle and brain look alike. Nice saying.

Comment: Just to clarify: To the best of my knowledge: (a) "Noodle" is an old slang term for "brain". I don't think it's used much today, at least I haven't read or heard it from any recent sources. But many people, especially older people, recognize it. (b) "Bake your noodle" is NOT a common phrase. I have never heard it before. Either the writer invented the phrase for this movie, or it's pretty rare. Nevertheless, the intended meaning isn't too hard to figure out.